# Javascript handle with special caracteres like ñ or ó

Tags: javascript

I have some data that comes from a csv file, and the original data have some special characters so when I load the data and do a console.log() the data appears with stuff like this `nari�o`

this is how the data looks like when I load it from the csv

```
{group: "nari�o", Moderada: 4, Baja: 11, Alta: 2}
{group: "choc�", Moderada: 6, Alta: 19, Baja: 1}
```

and the ideal would be something like this

```
{group: "nariño", Moderada: 4, Baja: 11, Alta: 2}
{group: "chocó", Moderada: 6, Alta: 19, Baja: 1}
```

I tried whit the function of [this post](https://locutus.io/php/xml/utf8_encode/) but didn't work, I think it is maybe because the data is already loaded and lost the characters I want to keep. Any ideas on how can I solve this?

This is how I load the data:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) { 
    console.log(data);//when I do this the data has already lost the characters like ñ or ó 
    //do some stuff with the data
    var dpto = d3.nest()
      .key(function(d) { return d.DEPTO.toLowerCase(); })
      .key(function(d) { return d.TEXTO_AMENAZA; })
      .rollup(function(v) { return v.length; })
      .object(data);  

      const result = Object.entries(dpto).reduce(
      (acc, [group, properties]) => [
      ...acc, { group, ...properties }
      ], []
      );

})
```

Comment: where is the file coming from? a web server? local file? how do you load the data?

Comment: the data comes from a local file, and I load it using D3js, because I make some graphs with that data

Comment: please post the code you are using.

Comment: Ok, I edit the post  with the part of the code that loads the data

Comment: so that file is being served over http i believe. you will have to ensure the proper http headers for encoding is et

Comment: Can you be more specific please? did you mean this `<meta charset="UTF-8">` in the index.html header? if so I already tried and didn't work

Comment: that’s in the html. It’s for the response from your web server

Comment: Ok but I added it in the html header and didn't work

Comment: not in your html. In your server

Comment: can you please tell me how? I'm actually running it in a local server via python -m http.server

Answer (score 0):

You should check that your csv file is in utf8 format or not, you can check that by opening your csv file in any text editor, like in below image of windows notepad's bottom bar

[image]

If your file is not in UTF8 format, In windows notepad you can go file > Save As and while saving the file select the utf8 encoding.

[image]

**Once you convert the file to utf8 all the special characters will work fine.**

and If you don't want to convert your file you can use [d3.dsvFormat](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/v1.2.0/README.md#dsvFormat) and pass the encoding your file is using, so that D3 knows what how to get the data in correct encoding. For that you need to refer [D3 documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv/blob/v1.2.0/README.md#dsvFormat)

Comment: @Akarii Hey does this answer solved your problem or it still exists?